How to correctly access container entities in Minecraft .mca files using anvil-parser?
I'm working on a project to read Minecraft .mca files, scan for container entities (chests, shulker boxes, furnaces, barrels), and save their contents into spreadsheets using anvil-parser. However, I'm encountering issues accessing the data correctly.
import os
import anvil
import json
import pandas as pd

def scan_chunk_for_containers(chunk):
    containers = []
    for entity in chunk.entities:
        if entity['id'] in ['minecraft:chest', 'minecraft:shulker_box', 'minecraft:furnace', 'minecraft:barrel']:
            containers.append(entity)
    return containers

def process_region_file(region_file_path, output_folder):
    region = anvil.Region.from_file(region_file_path)
    all_containers = []
    for chunk_x in range(32):
        for chunk_z in range(32):
            if region.chunk_location(chunk_x, chunk_z) is not None:
                try:
                    chunk = region.get_chunk(chunk_x, chunk_z)
                    containers = scan_chunk_for_containers(chunk)
                    all_containers.extend(containers)
                except anvil.errors.ChunkNotFound:
                    continue

    if all_containers:
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.basename(region_file_path) + '_containers.json')
        with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
            json.dump(all_containers, output_file, indent=4)
        
        # Convert to DataFrame and save as spreadsheet
        df = pd.json_normalize(all_containers)
        spreadsheet_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.basename(region_file_path) + '_containers.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(spreadsheet_path, index=False)
        print(f"Saved container data to {spreadsheet_path}")

def main():
    region_folder = "path goes here" 
    output_folder = "output path goes here"
    
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    
    for file_name in os.listdir(region_folder):
        if file_name.endswith('.mca'):
            region_file_path = os.path.join(region_folder, file_name)
            process_region_file(region_file_path, output_folder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'Chunk' object has no attribute 'sections'

How can I correctly access container entities? I tried some other ways but I feel like at this point I have no clue. The world is 1.20.4.

I was doing some searching myself as i wanted to find misplaced items in containers. I was using chunk = anvil.Chunk.from_region and chunk.data.get('block_entities', []) as everything is stored in block_entities.
So applying that to what you've done would be something like this
import os
import anvil
import json
import pandas as pd

def scan_chunk_for_containers(chunk):
    containers = []
    for entity in chunk.data.get('block_entities', []):
        if entity['id'].value in ['minecraft:chest', 'minecraft:shulker_box', 'minecraft:furnace', 'minecraft:barrel']:            
            x = entity['x'].value
            y = entity['y'].value
            z = entity['z'].value
            coords = f"{x},{y},{z}"
            if entity['Items']:
                for item in entity['Items']:
                    item_id = item['id'].value
                    item_count = item['count'].value
                    containers.append({ "Entity":entity['id'].value, 
                                        "Item": item_id, 
                                        "QTY": item_count, 
                                        "Location": coords })
    return containers

def process_region_file(region_file_path, output_folder):
    region = anvil.Region.from_file(region_file_path)
    all_containers = []
    for chunk_x in range(32):
        for chunk_z in range(32):
            try: 
                chunk = anvil.Chunk.from_region(region, chunk_x, chunk_z)
                if not chunk:
                    continue
                try:
                    containers = scan_chunk_for_containers(chunk)
                    all_containers.extend(containers)
                except KeyError as e:
                    continue
            except (anvil.errors.ChunkNotFound, KeyError) as e:
                continue

    if all_containers:
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.basename(region_file_path) + '_containers.json')
        with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
            json.dump(all_containers, output_file, indent=4)
        
        # Convert to DataFrame and save as spreadsheet
        df = pd.json_normalize(all_containers)
        spreadsheet_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.basename(region_file_path) + '_containers.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(spreadsheet_path, index=False)
        print(f"Saved container data to {spreadsheet_path}")

def main():
    region_folder = "path goes here" 
    output_folder = "output path goes here"
    
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    
    for file_name in os.listdir(region_folder):
        if file_name.endswith('.mca'):
            region_file_path = os.path.join(region_folder, file_name)
            process_region_file(region_file_path, output_folder)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

